# Responsive image, how to express full size height width as it is in the sprite sheet?

Tags: css, image, css-sprites

Final stages of my first Responsive site:

Divs are all in percents: ✔
Images are all background images using sprite sheets: ✔

Now need a solution to making the background sprite images scale with assorted devices.

I am very confused about the simplest way to get this done.

My non-scaling current syntax is this:

.PrettyPicture   {background:url(/dir/dir/PrettyPicture.png)no-repeat;background-position:-1px -32px;width:600px;height:300px;}

which, of course, does not scale.

I really can't figure this out. With all the tutorials, I don't see how to express the height and width of the full-size image in the sprite sheet.

Something is right in front of me that I do not see.

Thanks.

/Pat

Comment: This is what I have learned thusfar: scaling images for responsive design using conventional sprite sheets is possible through an intense manual process of calculating the image position in the sprite sheet to an x and y percent.

Comment: The formula is not intuitive at all. At this writing, early 2015, it seems all responsive image solutions require javascript or combination solutions with php and .htaccess.  One solution is [Picturefill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/).  Another one is [Advanced Images](http://www.adaptive-images.com/). Both seem reasonable to a novice to moderate webmaster. Picturefill requires several sized images per use, Advanced Images scales them at the server level.